# Neukirch, Lemma 6.2

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I understand the proof up to the final step. It says that this holds $\forall \epsilon > 0$ and since $|N_{K|\mathbb{Q}}(a)|$ is always a positive integers, the existence of an $a \in \mathfrak{a}, a \neq 0$ with the wanted property follows.

For me it seems like it uses some kind of continuity. Maybe the norm is a continuous function (but what would the topology be?) and the ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ is closed. But I'm not sure whether this makes sense.

[Neukirch, Proposition 5.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UprBY.png)

[Neukirch, Theorem 5.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXRgS.png)

[Neukirch, Lemma 6.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s7C1.png)

Comment: It's very hard to understand the idea of the proof since it seems to rely on several prior results...

Comment: I see, I was thinking that maybe someone read Neukirch and asked him/herself the same thing. Maybe it helps if I add 5.2 and 5.3.

Comment: You linked 5.2 twice instead of 5.3.

Comment: Oups, thanks. It should be correct now.

Comment: Neukirch points out that the absolute value of the norm is taking positive integer values. Write $a$ for the portion of the RHS without the $\epsilon$. If $a$ is an integer, then take $\epsilon = 1/2$. Otherwise, write $A$ for the smallest integer larger than $a$, and take $\epsilon = (A - a ) /2$.

Comment: @peterag oh wow, thank you so much! Makes perfect sense now!